# invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: javascript, syntax

When I automate my test case, for the first 5 people in the form, I am filling similar info which is going through, but for the sixth person, it fails because it has a different answer.

I have attached the `if` condition. I am using JavaScript and Nodejs,
is there any syntax error?

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYduS.jpg)

Comment: Could you post your code as text instead of an image? This will make it much easier to reproduce your problem and make corrections.

Comment: in the form when we select citizen as No, then the radio button and fields after that are enabled for legal resident. but when we say citizen Yes,  the radio button and fields after that are disabled. this method has missing part. it seems it doesn't have the code where it says when citizen is Yes, skip or ignore radio button and fields after that.

Answer (score 0):

citizenDataEntry(listOfApplicants) {
        listOfApplicants.forEach((applicant, i) => {
        let j = i < 10 ? `0${i}` : `${i}`
        if (applicant.name === $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.name).getText()) {
        applicant.citizen === 'Yes' ? $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.chkCitizenYes).click() : $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.chkCitizenNo).click();
        if (applicant.legalResident === 'Yes') {
        $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.chkLegalResidentYes).click();
        $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.dateOfLegalResident).setValue(applicant.dateOfLegalResident)
        } else {
        $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.chkLegalResidentNo).click();
        }
        $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.dateOfEntry).setValue(applicant.dateOfEntry);
        if (applicant.ssn !== undefined) $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.ssn).setValue(applicant.ssn);
        if (applicant.prucolAlien !== undefined) applicant.prucolAlien === 'Yes' ? $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.prucolAlienYes).click() : $(sel.part1Selector + j + sel.prucolAlienNo).click();
        }
        });
        }